# loading delay on new browser in angular2

Tags: angular

package.json

```
  {
 "name": "angular-quickstart",
 "version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
 "scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
 "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
"lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
"lite": "lite-server",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
"test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w"
 },
"keywords": [],
 "author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"mydatepicker": "^1.1.12",
"ng2-datepicker": "^1.4.7",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^3.1.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "~2.0.10",
"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.4",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~4.0.14",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
 },
 "repository": {}
}
```

Use to Get data from database

```
getQuestionList()  {                  
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');                
            let options = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: "FeedbackMaster.aspx/getQuestionList",                   
                headers: this.headers,
                body:{log:this.login}
            });
            return this._http.request(new Request(options)).retry(2)
            .map((response: Response)=>this.extractData(response))
            .do(data =>  {this.temp=data, console.log('getQuestionList:'+ JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.temp.d)))})
            .catch(this.handleError);                  
    }
```

Question.ts

```
QuestionList() {
this.dataService.getQuestionList().subscribe(
  tradeshows => {
    this.temoobj = tradeshows,
      this.QuestionMaster = JSON.parse(this.temoobj.d);
  },
  error => { console.error('QuestionList:\n\t ' + error); }
 );
}
```

When I try to run application on new browser

> First time it takes 40 second time for get data from database
>
> same browser when try for second time it takes only 3 to 4 second

why it takes 40 second loading time for first time  later on it loads in very few second I tried multiple time then not problem it takes me few second

then

```
why this problem occurs in first time loading for new browser ?

what is solution for that?
```

Comment: is web server iis?

Comment: yes I am  using IIS

Comment: Setup "Application Initialization" https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: So you mean its IIS problem let me check I will update it from IIS 7 to IIS8

Comment: Is this with AoT built deployable?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer  pls check package.json